# Como ajustar un JComponent encima de otros usando el GridBagLayout

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

**Hola Buenas!**

Resulta que estoy empezando a intentar usar el Gridbaglayout para poder hacer mis interfaces sin la ayuda de Herramientas de GUI como el Netbeans y actualmente estoy perdido..

Veran, Tengo una duda y es si es posible acomodar estos Componentes de esta misma manera a codigo manual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta donde llego lograr es aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya despues al momento de agregar el ultimo componente sucede esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es posible les agradezco que me lo digan.

Metodo con el cual agrego los componentes y los ubico:

SOLUCION: Se le agrego a cada JComponent una variable personal GridBagConstraints gracias a: @Javi Molla

```
public void topPanel(){

    pnlTop.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints clblNombre = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints cnameField = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints clblID = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints cidField = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints ccolorBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints cbtnAgregarIns = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints clblOr = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints cbtnAgregarVen = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints clblAgregarComo = new GridBagConstraints();
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    clblNombre.insets = i;
    clblNombre.gridx = 0;
    clblNombre.gridy = 1;
    pnlTop.add(lblNombre, clblNombre);
    cnameField.gridx = 1;
    cnameField.gridy = 1;
    nameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,23));
    pnlTop.add(nameField, cnameField);
    clblID.gridx = 2;
    clblID.gridy = 1;
    pnlTop.add(lblID, clblID);
    cidField.gridx = 3;
    cidField.gridy = 1;
    idField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,23));
    pnlTop.add(idField, cidField);
    ccolorBox.gridx = 4;
    ccolorBox.gridy = 1;
    pnlTop.add(colorBox, ccolorBox);
    cbtnAgregarIns.gridx = 5;
    cbtnAgregarIns.gridy = 1;
    pnlTop.add(btnAgregarIns, cbtnAgregarIns);
    clblOr.gridx = 6;
    clblOr.gridy = 1;
    pnlTop.add(lblOr, clblOr);
    cbtnAgregarVen.gridx = 7;
    cbtnAgregarVen.gridy = 1;
    pnlTop.add(btnAgregarVen, cbtnAgregarVen);
    clblAgregarComo.gridx = 6;
    clblAgregarComo.gridy = 0;
    pnlTop.add(lblAgregarComo, clblAgregarComo);
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías usar una variable GridBagConstraints nueva para cada componente ya que si no, puedes acabar modificando los valores anteriores y te puede descuadrar todo. Aunque sea un poco rollo, para cada componente haz un c = new GridBagConstraints(); e informa todas las propiedades necesarias cada vez

Comment: Y no hay solucion para lo otro? :(

Comment: Creo que lo que te he comentado es lo que causa tu problema. Arregla eso y actualiza el código si no te funciona

Comment: Ok, Entonces lo que dices es que es mejor que cada componente tenga su propia variable de ubicacion?

Comment: Sí, no solo mejor, es necesario

Comment: Genial amigo, Me solucionaste el problema, Actualizare el codigo de mi pregunta y ojala puedas poner una respuesta para yo ponerla como la correcta!

Comment: Oye amigo, Acabo de darme cuenta que se me soluciona lo del Label, Pero los TxtField se siguen encogiendo, Podrias ayudarme una vez mas?

Comment: Ya no, Ya logre arreglarlo, Gracias igualmente!

Comment: ¿La solución a tu respuesta es lo de tener una variable GridBagConstraints para cada control?

Comment: Si señor, Esa es

Comment: Sr Javi, Crees posible pasarme un articulo en el que me enseñen profundamente sobre el Gridbaglayout? Estaria super genial..

Comment: Pues no sé de ningún artículo pero buscando en Google aparece este por ejemplo: http://www.chuidiang.org/java/layout/GridBagLayout/GridBagLayout.php

Comment: Me servira, Gracias por todo amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar una instancia nueva de GridBagConstraints para cada componente ya que si no, puedes acabar modificando los valores anteriores y te puede descuadrar todo:

```
pnlTop.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.insets = i;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
pnlTop.add(lblNombre, c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
nameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,23));
pnlTop.add(nameField, c);
```